# How to remove 'Submitted By'?

Tags: nodes

Although there are many answers for earlier versions of Drupal 8, I could not find a way to remove 'Submitted by' information displayed with Articles.

How can one achieve this with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is in the settings of the content type:

> /admin/structure/types/manage/article

Here you'll find in the tab **Display settings** the checkbox:

> [x] Display author and date information